# Should I use of/with/or something else?

Tags: grammar

Should I use of/with/or something else? I think "of" is ok, but I am not sure if "with" is ok, and I am thinking there might be a better way to say this, but I am not sure.

Here's an example sentence:

> This is a comedy of Noah building an ark with a bunch of drunk people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write

> This is a comedy of Noah building an ark with a bunch of drunk people.

It is not an error in grammar. But "comedy of" seems awkward to me in this construction. I would be more likely to write:

> - This is a comedy **about** Noah building an ark with a bunch of drunk people.
> - This is a comedy **which features** Noah building an ark with a bunch of drunk people.

"Comedy of" is more often used when indicating the **kind** of comedy it is, such as "a comedy of manners", or "a comedy of misunderstanding", or "a comedy of missed timing".

Comment: Or ***...where Noah builds an ark...,*** for example. There are any number of different ways of phrasing the [syntactically optional] adjectival clause that convey much the same meaning.